# Find closest id in a given class, add to data-target in another class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a database which dynamically adds rows to an HTML table using the `.append` method in jQuery. In each of these rows there is a hidden row which can be toggled with the [Boostrap accordian method](http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/QLfMU/1/). Once these rows are appended the script generates a unique ID for the bootstrap `.accordian-body` in each row. The format for this ID is `#ui-id-1`, `#ui-id-2` and so on. Each row opens the `.accordian-body` via the HTML5 `data-target` selector, but as each ID is generated uniquely I need a way of finding out this ID so that the `.accordian-toggle` appended in each row correctly toggles its *nearest* `.accordian body`.

I figured an easy workaround for this would be for each row to find the nearest ID in the `.accordian-body` class and dynamically add the `data-target` to the selector in the `.accordian-toggle` class via jQuery. Is there an easy way to do this? I've searched around and not found much about how to add to / replace the `data-target` selector in jQuery.

This is currently how the code is structured:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var tr = $("<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#ui-id-1' class='accordian-toggle'/>");
    tr.append....
    tr.append("<td colspan='11' class='hiddenRow'><div class='accordian-body collapse'>...</div></td>

    $(".accordian-body").each(function() {
    $(this).uniqueId();
});
});
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. Maybe you could post a portion of the relevant (generated) html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you say "**in** each of these rows there is a hidden row", hinting that one is a container; yet the fiddle you linked to shows these as sibling rows rather than parent > child. Anyways, assuming thy are in fact siblings.. you can use next() in combination with `tr[id*="ui-id-"]` to find the "nearest" sibling element, with an id containing `ui-id-#` it precedes. If one is nested within the other, you can use find() to traverse down and closest() to traverse up. You can use `.data( key, value )` to set the value of the target. Hope this helps

BTW.. Personally I would either interpolate the id of the record at hand into the toggle/target attributes once you load it from the database or just add a click event for table rows,excluding hidden rows.. to simply show and hide the row that follows it. Add the event to the table and listen in on rows so that it works for dynamically appended rows : http://jsfiddle.net/QLfMU/51/

Comment: Thanks, that's pointing me in the right direction! I've had a play around with the idea but I'm unsure of the syntax with the `.data` part. So far I've got: `$(".accordian-toggle").each(function() {
    $(this).next(tr[id*="ui-id-"]).find()` but I'm unsure how to approach the next part once the id is found.

Comment: Added another possible solution for you in my answer, in case you're having trouble with the previous route.. you may want to cache the query for `next()` as to not repeat it in both the `if` and the `toggle`..but its overall, a much simpler approach

Comment: Yes definitely a simpler way of doing this - thanks for your help, much appreciated!